# Postfix login mismatch sender address rejected

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'm getting the following rather annoying error message:

```
Sender address rejected: not owned by user subscription@****.ca; from=<subscription@****.ca> to=<webmaster@****.ca> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.2.34]>
```

And my `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/99-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 104857600
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = ****.ca
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_milters = unix:/spamass/spamass.sock unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-chain-mail-****.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-key-decrypted-mail-****.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Basically, I can't send mail from outside the local network! If I remove `reject_sender_login_mismatch` from the options I can, but this seems bad... My mailbox maps has all the main email accounts. (I starred-out my domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the query variable in 'mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf'

from: `query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'`

to: `query = SELECT email FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'`.

It didn't work before because it needs to match the 'FROM' header to the return value of the query (reject_sender_login_mismatch) explains this.

Comment: But you should use virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf. So in master.cf: 
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=proxy:mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf

Answer (score 2):

Replace [reject_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) with [reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch) will do the trick.

### Explanation

In postfix main.cf, parameter `reject_sender_login_mismatch` [was an alias for](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/reject-sender-login-mismatch-behavior-tp61478p61498.html) `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch`.

The reason why outside network can't send email is `reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch` (which is parts of  `reject_sender_login_mismatch`) will rejects sender which isn't defined in [smtpd_sender_login_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps).

For further explanation of this three parameter, I suggest to take a look [in this discussion](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Question-about-reject-unauthenticated-sender-login-mismatch-td27610.html).

Comment: Alright, I'll try that when I get home. It seems strange though that it doesn't work as is - I should be authenticated, and all the accounts are defined in the MySQL db.

Comment: I'm thinking it's because my query is `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE email=%s`. I'll change it to `SELECT email FROM TABLE WHERE email=%s` and let you know if that works

Answer (score 0):

Please check your master.cf,you seem to be using the wrong map.

You should use virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf. So in master.cf:

```
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=proxy:mysql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
```

and not /usr/local/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

It uses this query to see if the email belongs to the mailbox owner (the goto):

```
query = SELECT goto FROM mail2_alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = 1
```